# conda: packages found to be in conflict, but only ONE package is listed. What does this mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, ncl

I'm trying to install the NCAR command language suite `ncl`, which has some data processing tools for atmospheric scientists. Every time I get the message:

```sh
conda create -n ncl -c conda-forge ncl
.....
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
    -ncl
```

But how can packages be in conflict when `ncl` is the only package listed? What does this mean?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on macOS. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Download/conda.shtml:

NOTE: There is a known issue with the NCL conda-forge package that causes an "UnsatisfiableError" in conda:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- ncl
As of 2017-12-20, we have a workaround for this issue that forces a "broken" version of GDAL to be installed:

```
conda create -n ncl_fix -c conda-forge -c conda-forge/label/broken ncl poppler=0.52 xerces-c=3.1 gsl
```

Comment: first, provide explanation than post the link in the answer.